# How would I go about structuring this data in Redis?

Tags: data-structures, redis

Here is an example of what I want my data structure to look like:

```
[games]:
   [game_1]:
       players: 10
       maxPlayers: 24
       state: "PLAYING"
       currentMap: "Example Map"
   [game_2]:
       players: 0
       maxPlayers: 24
       state: "LOBBY"
       currentMap: "None"
```

I am using the Java implementation of `Redis` (`Jedis`) in order to cache data from registered game servers. A proxy server connects all the registered game servers together, however, the proxy cannot relay data such as this. Therefore, I have gone with the `Redis` approach and integrated it into the core plugin which is shared across all of the game servers. The `lobby` server will be able to access the data from `Redis` to display live game statistics to the players. How would I go about structuring this? I'm fairly new to `Redis` and hours of searching did not help. Please do explain this in simple terms. 
I would like to be able to make method calls to get the data for a specific game and iterate through all cached games in the `Redis` database. (e.g. games: {"`game_1`", "`game_2`"})

Answer (score 2):

One way to go about this would be:

1. Store your games in Hashes - a Hash per game. The Hash's key name should be your game's identifier and the fields->values in it should correspond to your game's properties. In Redis lingo that should be done with:

   `HMSET game_1 players 10 maxPlayers 24 state PLAYING currentMap "Example Map"`
2. Updates to a game can simply call `HSET game_1 players 11` to touch specific properties.
3. You can get read a specific game's property, properties or all properties with `HGET`, `HMGET` and `HGETALL` respectively.
4. Getting all the games can be done in one of two ways:

   a. Use `SCAN` to retrieve the key names in your database, and call the APIs in step 3 on each. Pro: no additional maintenance, con: could be slower.

   b. Maintain a Set of that consists of your game identifiers (key names) - to fetch all games, get the contents of that Set and for each of its members use the APIs in step 3. Pro: better performance for fetching all games, con: requires maintaining another data structure (the Set).